# PHP echo In a while Loop for Multiple variable

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to echo some results
here $aditya is a array which contains multiple value
and $var3 also contains multiple value
but when i am echoing it it showing only one value

please figure out what wrong i am doing

```
$query1= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE col2 in ($aditya)");

while($var1=mysql_fetch_array($query1))
{

$var2=$var1['col1'];
$var3=$var1['col2'];
$var4=$var1['col3'];

 $name=mysql_query("SELECT f_name FROM table2 WHERE f_id=$var2");
$tname=mysql_fetch_array($name);



   echo "</br>"."</br>"."<a style='color:blue' href=something.php?f_id=$var2   target=_BLANK >".$name['f_name']."</a>"." "."$var3"." "."("."$var4".")";

}
```

Comment: If $aditya is array then you should change your SQL query like this,

$query1= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE col2 in (".implode(', ', $aditya).")");

Comment: dump the arrays inside the while loop to see what they contain; `print_r($var1)`

Comment: @MuthuKumaran.. i am doing that in a seperate query  
$aditya = implode(',', $ids_array);

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the problem comes from your query.
Put `echo $query1; exit;` and try it in phpmyadmin if u have such.
Other approach to see what you get from the query is to place:

```
echo $var1['col1'].", ".$var1['col2'].", ".$var1['col3'];
```

in the while() to see what u get from the query.
The problem isn't in the echo for sure.

**UPDATE 2**

```
$query1 = ("
    SELECT unique_ids, GROUP_CONCAT( whatuwant )
    FROM table
    WHERE col2 in ($aditya)
    GROUP BY unique_ids
");
```

Comment: I think you should put this as a comment.

Comment: @Martin did that, it is echoing, but it is echoing seperate records for two diff attributes of same id , i want to concatenate that.
        19, text1, 1
        19, text2, 1
i want something like 19, text1(1),text2(1)

Answer (score 0):

If $aditya really is an array then it's impossible to use it the way you are in your query. MySQL expects a comma separated list of elements, so you could implode the PHP array and feed it to the query:

```
$query1= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE col2 in (" . implode(',', $aditya) . ")");
```

Besides that you might wanna consider giving your variables more meaningful names, because you'll only confuse yourself and other coders working on your projects if you name them $var1, $var2 etc. Just a hint.

Answer (score 0):

So many things might be wrong here

A. `$aditya` was not properly defined. If its an array then you need to combine it with `implode` if noy make sure its properly formatted

Expected Output should be like this

```
 SELECT * FROM table  WHERE col2  IN ( 250, 220, 170 );
```

B. `$name` is not an array so `$name['f_name']` would not work. You use use `$tname['f_name']` instead

C.  I think you need to update your question with the exact error you are having your code as so many things that can go run that we can not test remotely eg. Does a table name `table` even exist in the first place